# how to format tooltip in rc-slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

I am using react `rc-slider`. I want to add tooltip to display current value I am following [rc-slider github post](http://react-component.github.io/slider/examples/handle.html). but my slider position got fixed. and once tooltip appeared and it is not disappearing. my slider looks likes this

[image: slider snapshot]

Related code is below

```
const handle = () =>(

       <Tooltip
      prefixCls="rc-slider-tooltip"
      overlay={this.props.value}
      visible={true}
      placement="top"
      key={0}
    >
      <Handle value={this.props.value}  />
    </Tooltip>
```

And my render is

```
    return (

      <Slider
        min={this.props.minValue}
        max={this.props.maxValue}
        marks={marks}
        disabled={this.props.disabled}
        step={this.props.step}
        onChange={this.updateValue.bind(this)}
        value={this.props.value}
        handle={handle}
       // tipFormatter={value => `${value}%`}
        onAfterChange={value => this.props.updateValue(value)}
      />
)
```

please help me how to improve this

Comment: Are there any erro in console ?

Comment: if I use `Range` it is but for `slider` no

Answer (score 5):

I end up using `createSliderWithTooltip` of rc-slider below is my updated code

```
import Slider, { createSliderWithTooltip } from 'rc-slider';

const SliderWithTooltip = createSliderWithTooltip(Slider);
 <SliderWithTooltip
        min={this.props.minValue}
        max={this.props.maxValue}
        marks={marks}
        disabled={this.props.disabled}
        step={this.props.step}
        onChange={this.updateMixValue.bind(this)}
        value={this.props.value}
              onAfterChange={value => this.props.MixValue(getValues(value))}
      />
```

and in scss file added like this

```
  .rc-slider-mark{
                padding-top:7px;
            }
            .rc-slider-step{
                span{
                    background-color: rgb(44, 71, 112);
    border-color: rgb(44, 71, 112);
                }
            }
            .rc-slider-handle{
                background-color: #5bc0de;
                border-color: #5bc0de;
            }
```